# Multiple select from one table and insert into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an oldDB and I want to split one table of oldDB (`tblCustomers`) in to two tables of newDB (`Customer` and `ReservedService`) as follows:

### OldDB

**tblCustomers:** (Code, Name, Phone, Address, Duration, Price)

---

### NewDB

**Customer:** (Id, Code, Name, Phone, Address)

**ReservedService:** (Id, CustomerId, Duration, Price)

---

I have try these two queries:

query1:

```
use newDB
insert into newDB.dbo.Customer([Code], [Name], [Address], Phone) 
select Code, SUBSTRING(Name,1,50), SUBSTRING(Address,1,100), SUBSTRING(Phone,1,50)
from oldDB.dbo.tblCustomers
```

query2:

```
use newDB
    insert into newDB.dbo.ReservedService(CustomerId, Duration, Price) 
    select `????`, SUBSTRING(Duration,1,50), SUBSTRING(Price,1,100)
    from oldDB.dbo.tblCustomers
```

Notice that I have two problems:

1. merge these two queries in one query
2. in second query the select statement should retrieve data from two tables (retrive `CusttomerId` from `newDB.Customer` and retrieve other fields from `oldDB.tblCustomers`)

How can I integrate these two queries in one query without two mentioned problems?

Comment: You need one INSERT per table.

Comment: What is your question here? You state that you have problems, but don't ask anything.

Comment: Is `Customer.Id` column in the new table an Identity column ? Also is `tblCustomers.Code` in the old table a unique column, in simple words,   You don't have One customer with multiple codes or Two different customers with the same code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fateme, you can use [SQL Output clause](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/output-clause-sample-code-with-insert-update-delete-sql-server-2005.aspx) in order to get identity value (as Customer table Id column value) and then use it for ReservedService table as follows

```
declare @t table (
    customerid int, code varchar(10)
)

insert into Customer (
    Code, Name, Phone, Address
)
output
    inserted.id, inserted.code
into @t(customerid, code)
select Code, Name, Phone, Address
from tblCustomers

insert into ReservedService (
    CustomerId, Duration, Price
)
select CustomerId, Duration, Price
from tblCustomers
inner join @t as t
    on t.code = tblCustomers.Code
```

You can realize that I used a variable table to store Id and Code relation for later use during Insert command for ReservedService

I hope it helps

Comment: The answer is based on a couple of arbitrary assumptions, 1 -   `tblCustomers.Code` in the old table is a unique column. 2 - `dbo.Customer.ID` is an Identity column. If either of the assumptions are not true, the actual solution could look a lot different.

Comment: @M.Ali you are right for the Code column, it should be unique. And the Customer table ID column, this does not exist in original data so I thought we are free to set it. It is just for use as a foreign key target in ReservedServices table. There seems to be no reason not to create it as an IDENTITY value. Of course, we can arbitrarily assign a value for each customer record in the first table, tblCustomers and use it as CustomerId. Actually this will make the solution easier

Comment: I never suggested to make arbitrary data I said your answer was based on  arbitrary assumptions about the data. However Identity column seems to be the way to go in this scenario.